# VBA/Excel - Reset Checkbox Macro is getting Compile Error: Expected: identifier

Tags: vba, excel

My macro is as follows:

```
Sub resetCheckBoxes()
    Dim ckBox As CheckBox
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
        For Each ckBox In WS.CheckBoxes
                ckBox.Value = False
        Next ckBox
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This macro worked a week ago. I tried running it today and now I'm getting the compile error. The only thing that has changed was my computer got a Microsoft update.

Comment: with Excel 2013 e W7Pro SP1 it works

Comment: The code only works for checkboxes from the Form Control Toolbox

Comment: With my Excel 2016 MSO(16.0.9126.2116) it runs ok with worksheet checkboxes. I tested it with a button on the worksheet..

Answer (score 1):

As @Davesexcel mentionned "The code only works for checkboxes from the Form Control Toolbox"

With Active X Control Toolbox I think you'll need the code below :

```
    Sub resetCheckBoxes()
            Dim obj As OLEObject

            Dim WS As Worksheet
            Set WS = ActiveSheet

            For Each obj In WS.OLEObjects
                If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                    obj.Object.Value = False
                End If
            Next obj
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still getting the compile error even with this code instead of what I had before. The checkboxes are still form control ones, they shouldn't have changed to Active X.

Comment: I can't figure out where the error come from, both codes works for me  just fine .. Try to debug your code with F8 to see which line gives the error exactly ..

Comment: So the issue has resolved itself from what I could tell. I tried making it a Private Sub and then deleted everything out and put it back in as a regular Sub and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for all the help!